# Grails: XML Handling

Tags: xml, grails

I have two questions and I hope someone can support me:

#### 1. how can I respond XML inside a Grails controller?

As an example, I parse a simple XML and want to return this XML String from the parser:

`curl http://localhost:8080/test/xml -H "Accept: application/xml"`

```
class TestController {
    static responseFormats = ['xml']

    def index() {
        String xml = "<a><b>abcd</b><b>defg</b></a>"
        Node parsed = new XmlParser().parseText(xml)
        StringWriter stringWriter = new StringWriter()
        XmlNodePrinter nodePrinter = new XmlNodePrinter(new PrintWriter(stringWriter))
        nodePrinter.setPreserveWhitespace(true)
        nodePrinter.print(parsed)
        String xmlOut = stringWriter.toString()
        respond xmlOut, formats: ['xml']
    }
}
```

If I use `render xmlOut` instead of `respond xmlOut, formats: ['xml']` I get the XML back, but I'm not sure, if this is the right way.

#### 2. How can I parse an XML string into an appropriate object?

Is there a way, where e.g. I can just load an XML file and map it to a class structure:

```
class A {
  List<B> b;
}

String xml = "<a><b>abcd</b><b>defg</b></a>"

A a = parse(xml)
```

Thank you in advance!

Regards

Comment: What version of Grails are you using?

Comment: I'm using v4.0.12